# what is the query equivalence in postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

what is the equivalence query on postgresql?

Build database and tables

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS lemonade;

use lemonade;

CREATE TABLE users (
    id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL auto_increment,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE memories (
    id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL auto_increment,
    content varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    userID int,
    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES users(id)
);

INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES ("Ruan", "ruan@gmail.com");
INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES ("Pereira", "pereira@gmail.com");

INSERT INTO memories (content, userID) VALUES ("memoria 1", 1);
INSERT INTO memories (content, userID) VALUES ("memoria 2", 1);
INSERT INTO memories (content, userID) VALUES ("memoria 3", 2);
INSERT INTO memories (content, userID) VALUES ("memoria 4", 2);
```

query on mysql:

```
select ANY_VALUE(m.id), ANY_VALUE(m.content), m.userID, ANY_VALUE(u.id), ANY_VALUE(u.name), ANY_VALUE(u.email) from memories m inner join users u on m.userID = u.id group by userID;
```

result:
[image with result of my query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSSIR.png)

query on postgresql:

?

result: expect result equal of up image

Comment: You tagged MySQL and Postgresql - why was MySQL tagged? What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I do not think I should have tagged the mysql tag. I tried many things that I can not even remember.

Answer (score 1):

The `ANY_VALUE` function in MySQL is used when a query is doing a `GROUP BY` aggregation, but columns are being selected which are not mentioned in the `GROUP BY` clause nor appear inside aggregate functions.  In the context of your query, this means that the only columns which can be selected are the `userID` or another column inside an aggregate function like `MAX` or `SUM`.  Technically you can also select other columns from the `users` table as well, assuming they are functionally dependent on the `userId`.  As the name implies, `ANY_VALUE` is telling MySQL to return any value for that column from each group of records.

As far as I know/expect, the value you get from `ANY_VALUE` is not guaranteed to be deterministic, and so would be logically equivalent to selecting a random value for that column from each group of records.  Assuming you do not care which values you get back, in Postgres you could arbitrarily just select the earliest memory for each user:

```
SELECT
    memory_id, content, id, name, email
FROM
(
    SELECT m.id AS memory_id, m.content, u.id, u.name, u.email,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.id ORDER BY m.id) rn
    FROM memories m
    INNER JOIN users u
        ON m.userID = u.id
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

I think that in general you should avoid using `ANY_VALUE` in MySQL unless you absolutely have no other choice.  A better long term solution would be to clean up the MySQL query and make it ANSI compliant.  Then it would be straightforward how to port it to another database.

Comment: in this sql query, occurrence this error: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ksXIeTwV_tHzx9qVL-UwMLNq96FTZ3Qj

Comment: @RuanNawe Your query is missing an alias `t` on the subquery.  Try running my _exact_ query from the answer.

Comment: the error persisted https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ksXIeTwV_tHzx9qVL-UwMLNq96FTZ3Qj

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: all these images are in the mysql database

Comment: Did you try my updated answer?  It should run on Postgres without error AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `DISTINCT ON ( expression ...)` clause.

New code is

```
select distinct on(u.id)
m.id, m.content, m.userID, u.id, u.name, u.email 
from memories m 
inner join users u on m.userID = u.id;
```

Note: `DISTINCT ON` is  Non-Standard SQL Clause.

Form more information [see](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

Comment: Please also quote the most relevant part of the linked page as links may expire :)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and simply solved it by using a `min` function. It works also on string columns. In your case it would give:

```
SELECT
  m.userID, 
  min(m.id) as id, 
  min(m.content) as content, 
  min(u.id) as uid, 
  min(u.name) as name, 
  min(u.email) as email 
FROM memories m 
INNER JOIN users u on m.userID = u.id 
GROUP BY userID;
```

If you were ready to use `any_value`, then it means that you don't care which value to return. Take the minimum one is one of those random values.